# Replacing missing values by the mean of the two previous and the two following values

Tags: python, windows

I'm new here and I've been struggling with this code and was wondering if anyone could help me.

As the title indicates, I want to replace missing values of an excel sheet with the mean value of the two previous and two following values.

The Excel sheet only has two columns. It looks like this:

```
A : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9 ,10....

B: 4, 7, 3 ,1, missing value, 5,30,14,27 ....
```

So for the first missing value, I want to have the mean of [3,1] and [5,30]

I am working with python. is a df.fillna or a df.replace function more suitable? And does anyone have an idea who to write that kind of code?

I'm super grateful for any help!

I already asked chatgpt, but the function it provided didn't work. I also tried googling about it, but couldn't find anything with the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

An example of solution might be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example DataFrame (comment this when reading from xlsx file)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': list(range(1, 11)),
    'B': [4, 7, 3, 1, np.nan, 5, 30, 14, 27, np.nan]
})

# (Uncomment when reading from xlsx file)
# df = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx')

# To compute the rolling mean of the previous 2 and next 2 values for each row in column B
df['B'] = df['B'].fillna((df['B'].shift(-2).rolling(2).mean() + df['B'].shift(2).rolling(2).mean()) / 2)

print(df)
```

Output of interpreter:

```
    A      B
0   1   4.00
1   2   7.00
2   3   3.00
3   4   1.00
4   5  11.25
5   6   5.00
6   7  30.00
7   8  14.00
8   9  27.00
9  10    NaN
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! My data set is much longer than just 11 values though. Can I somehow refer to the excel sheet for B ? because I can't type over 300 values for B...

Comment: Yes, as you can see i added *df = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx')*. That permits you to read directly the excel file.

Comment: So I put the "df=pd.read...." instead of the [4,7,3,1,np.nan....]?

Comment: Yes @ChrisbBacon

Comment: alright, thank you very much I will try it right now!

Comment: somehow it's not working unfortunetely. it suddenly tells me that it can't find my excel data. do i have to define it differently now? I used df= pd.read and the file path

Comment: Put the xlsx file in the same folder of the python file.

Comment: it now tells me there is a key error with 'B'. since I substituted the A-B part in the beginning with df = pd.read... there is no B anymore..

Comment: If it's possible can you post here a link to the dataset?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a link and I also can not yet use the chat to share data...

Comment: Ok, then as a last try you can do this: write *print(df)* before *df['B'] = df['B'].fillna...* and see which is the name of the column B in your case. Then change the name you see into every *'B'* of *df['B'] = df['B'].fillna...*

Comment: I tried but somehow it's still not working... tbh I don't know any further anymore...  I will try later again...

Answer (score 0):

@ChrisbBacon, you put it instead of this entire block: `df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': list(range(1, 11)), 'B': [4, 7, 3, 1, np.nan, 5, 30, 14, 27, np.nan] })`. The first element is a manual approach to creating a dataframe with Pandas. The second is the approach to create one by reading in an xlsx-file.

An alternative approach to solve this is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, None, 4, 5, 6, None, 8,9],
                   "B" : [4, 7, 3 ,1, None, 5,30,14,27]})

# find all missing values and return tuple with a list of column places and row places
np_positions = np.where(pd.isnull(df))
# create a list with the combination of row and column for each missing value
empty_values = [(row,col) for row,col in zip(*np_positions)]

# for every missing value
for empty in empty_values:
    # take the row and column
    pos_x, pos_y = empty
    # add the mean of the two numbers above and the mean of the numbers below it and divide by two
    fill_value = (df.iloc[pos_x-2:pos_x, pos_y].mean() + df.iloc[pos_x+1:pos_x+3, pos_y].mean())/2
    # place the value in the missing place
    df.iloc[pos_x, pos_y] = fill_value
```

Comment: thank your very much for your reply!! I tried to substitute the df=pd.read.... for the entire A and B Block, but it suddenly tells me that it can't find my file. I previously defined my file with: df= pd.read and the file path. Also, when I entered you alternative approach nothing happened. How can I excecute it?

Comment: Have you tried putting the python file and the xlsx-file in the same folder, and then running it from there? Otherwise, an explicit path, something like "C:/my document/my_file.xlsx", as a filepath.

Comment: it can now find the file, thank! However there is now a KeyError with 'B', because i now substituted the whole A-B dataframe with the short df=pd.read_.... When using your alternative approach nothing happens, how can I tell python to look for the np positions and then use the approach you mentioned? I already entered df.isnull or df.isnull.sum

Comment: Very good, that you got the file to load to a dataframe. Which solution are you trying? Mine does not use the column names and therefore shouldn't give a Key error.

Comment: I entered all your code from "# find all missing" and below. I didn' enter the pd. DataFrame part. Or should I add that and change the names?

Comment: You'll need the two imports as well. And then the first thing must be "df = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx')". See if that works.

Comment: I imported numpy and pandas and now when I entered the last part "for empty in empty...." it just shows a green tick but it doesn't show me any new values. Somehow python doesn't use my data?

Comment: This might have to do with the way the missing values are actual represented in your data. Both solutions work because the cells are truely empty. If there is a space or the text 'missing value' they wouldn't work in their current form. Could you do 'print(np_positions)' and provide this outcome from your console? And also a the outcome of 'print(pd.head(*number*))' where the number is large enough to include at least one missing value.